# Cutting string after x chars at whitespace in python

Tags: python

I want to cut a long text after x characters, but I don't want to cut a word in the middle, I want to cut at the last whitespace before x chars:

```
'This is a sample text'[:20]
```

gives me

```
'This is a sample tex'
```

but I want

```
'This is a sample'
```

Another example:

```
'And another sample sentence'[:15]
```

gives me

```
'And another sam'
```

but I want

```
'And another'
```

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now in **2022**, I discovered that `textwrap` from stdlibs, which [Steve thankfully recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18693671/2681631), has a method exactly for this need: [textwrap.shorten()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.shorten).

```
>>> import textwrap
>>> textwrap.shorten("This is a sample text", width=20, placeholder="")
'This is a sample'
```

It was introduced before Python 3.6, so should be available in most projects now.

Answer (score 25):

```
import textwrap
lines = textwrap.wrap(text, 20)
# then use either
lines[0]
# or
'\n'.join(lines)
```

Comment: That... is amazing. +1. This is what makes python brilliant. (you might want to add `[0]` at the end)

Comment: This returns a list, but is otherwise a great idea. Add `[0]` and you've won the internetz.

Comment: ``lines = textwrap.wrap(text, 20)`` ``'\n'.join(lines)`` : the doc says it is ``textwrap.fill(text, 20)``

Comment: If you wanted joined lines, you could use `textwrap.fill()`, which does exactly that.

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`str.rpartition()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) or [`str.rsplit()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) to remove everything after the last space of the remainder:

```
example[:20].rpartition(' ')[0]

example[:20].rsplit(' ', 1)[0]
```

The second argument to `str.rsplit()` limits the split to the first space from the right, and the `[0]` index takes whatever was split off before that space.

`str.rpartition()` is a bit faster, and always returns three strings; if there was no space then the first string returned is empty, so you may want to stick with `str.rsplit()` if that’s a possibility (that version would return a list with a single string in that case, so you end up with the original string again).

Answer (score 2):

Upvoted the two other answers, but just for the fun, with regex:

```
import re

r = re.compile('.{,20}(?<! )(?= |\Z|\A)')
for s in ('This is a sample text',
          'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  ',
          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
          'This is 1 first sample text  ',
          'This is 1 again sample text',
          'A great blank          here',
          'Another blank     here',
          'A short text',
          '  little indent',
          '                      great indent',
          'ocean',
          '!',
          ''):
    print ('-----------------------\n'
           " ....5...10...15...20\n"
           '%r\n%r'
           % (s, r.match(s).group() )   )
```

result

```
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'This is a sample text'
'This is a sample'
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz  '
''
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
''
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'This is 1 first sample text  '
'This is 1 first'
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'This is 1 again sample text'
'This is 1 again'
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'A great blank          here'
'A great blank'
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'Another blank     here'
'Another blank'
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'A short text'
'A short text'
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'  little indent'
'  little indent'
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'                      great indent'
''
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'ocean'
'ocean'
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
'!'
'!'
-----------------------
 ....5...10...15...20
''
''
```